# How to try-except and sql table syntax error in Python?

Tags: python, try-except

I have a code that puts some concatenated files into an SQL table (it's a loop). There's a configuration file where python reads the table name it should create and use in this code. It works just fine.

This is the code I execute:

```
            startSQL = time.time()

            #write the concatenated files into the database. Chunksize may be changed
            xls.to_sql(table, con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False, chunksize=10000)

            #count inserted rows _ information for the log table
            countRow=engine.execute("select count(*) from "+table+ ";").fetchall()
            finalCount = (str(countRow).split('[(')[1].split(',)]')[0])
            

            endSQL = time.time()
            elapsed_timeSQL = round(endSQL-startSQL,2)

            logging.info("Table Creation+{}+{}+0+{}".format(table, elapsed_timeSQL,finalCount))
            
            #Just to confirm the table was created - can be deleted
            x=pd.read_sql("SELECT top 5 * FROM "+table , engine)
            print(x, 3 * "\n");
```

It does what it's needed.

However, there are some syntaxes that you shouldn't use to create a table such as numbers, spaces, hyphens, etc. (as you can see in the following [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15) )

What I need is to implement a try-catch or whatever to make sure that if an error occurs, it logs the error, but continues the rest of the code execution.

NOTE:

E.g. when I type the table name as  `5table` it gives me the following error and stops the script and that is exactly what I want to avoid! I want it to write a log saying that it failed and continue the code.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/XXX/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1820, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "/home/XXX/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 732, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '5X'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "XXX.py", line 353, in <module>

  File "XXX.py", line 339, in main
    fh.close()
  File "XXX.py", line 123, in process_file
    engine.execute("drop TABLE if exists "+table);
  File "<string>", line 2, in execute
  File "/home/XXX/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/deprecations.py", line 401, in warned
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/XXX/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3176, in execute
    return connection.execute(statement, *multiparams, **params)
  File "/home/XXX/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1296, in execute
    future=False,
  File "/home/XXX/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1602, in _exec_driver_sql
    distilled_parameters,
  File "/home/XXX/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1863, in _execute_context
    e, statement, parameters, cursor, context
  File "/home/XXX/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2044, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    sqlalchemy_exception, with_traceback=exc_info[2], from_=e
  File "/home/XXX/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/home/XXX/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1820, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "/home/XXX/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 732, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '5E'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")
[SQL: drop TABLE if exists 5XXXX_example]
```

What I need is something like:

```
try:
        #do the code above

except:
        #if there's the error regarding table syntax, write to the log and continue whatever it's doing
        print("Failed table {} creation!".format(table))
        logging.error("Failed creation of table+{}+0+0+0".format(table))
```

Please, help...

Comment: `ProgrammingError` seemes to be the thrown Error, so with `except ProgrammingError:` it should catch the error

Comment: something like


    except ProgrammingError:
        pass
        print("Failed table {} creation!".format(table))
        logging.error("Failed creation of table+{}+0+0+0".format(table))
?

Comment: Note that the exception must be imported `from sqlalchemy.exc import ProgrammingError`

Comment: I did that, but it still gives me the exact same error

Answer (score 0):

The Error can be caught like so:

```
from sqlalchemy.exc import ProgrammingError

try:
    #do the code above
except ProgrammingError:
    #if there's the error regarding table syntax, write to the log and continue whatever it's doing
    print("Failed table {} creation!".format(table))
    logging.error("Failed creation of table+{}+0+0+0".format(table))
```

Edited my answer based on a comment from an other user

Comment: I tried this and didn't work

Comment: Didn't work. Same error :(